# Integrating over iid exponential(B = 1). (Is someone able to spot my mistake?)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

### Question:

Suppose that Y1, Y2, and Y3 are iid exponential random variables with β = 1. Show that
U = Y1 + Y2 + Y3 follows Gamma(3, 1) distribution, using the cdf method.

### Work:

$F_{U}(u) = P(U \le u) = P(Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 \le u)$

$P(Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 \le u) = \int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y_3}\int_{0}^{u - y_2 - y_3}e^{-(y_1 + y_2 + y_3)}dy_1dy_2dy_3$

\begin{align}
P(Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 \le u ) &= \int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y3}\int_{0}^{u - y_2 - y_3}e^{-(y_1 + y_2 + y_3)} dy_1dy_2dy_3\notag \\
&= \int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y_3}e^{-(y_2 + y_3)}\int_{0}^{u - y_2 - y_3}e^{-y_1}dy_1dy_2dy_3\notag \\
&= \int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y_3}e^{-(y_2 + y_3)}\times(-1)e^{-y_1}|_0^{u - y_2 - y_3}dy_2dy_3\notag \\
&=  \int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y3}-e^{-(y_2 + y_3)}\times (e^{-u+y_2+y_3}-1) dy_2dy_3 \notag \\
&=\int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y3}-e^{u +y_2 - y_2 + y_3 - y_3} + e^{-y_2-y_3} dy_2dy_3 \notag \\
&=\int_{0}^{u}\begin{bmatrix}-e^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y3}dy_2 + e^{-y3}\int_{0}^{u - y3}e^{-y_2}dy_2 \end{bmatrix} dy_3\notag \\
&=\int_{0}^{u}\begin{bmatrix}-e^{-u}y_2|_0^{u-y_3} + e^{-y_3}\times -e^{-y_2}|_0^{u-y_3}\end{bmatrix}dy_3 \notag \\
&=\int_{0}^{u}-e^{-u}\times (u-y_3) + e^{-y_3}\times (-e^{-u+y_3} + 1)\; dy_3 \notag \\
&=\int_{0}^{u}-ue^{-u}+e^{-u}y_3 - e^{-u}+ e^{-y_3}\; dy_3 \notag \\
&=-ue^{-u}\int_{0}^{u}dy_3 + e^{-u}\int_{0}^{u}y_3dy_3- e^{-u}\int_{0}^{u}dy_3 + \int_{0}^{u}e^{-y_3}dy_3 \notag \\
&=-ue^{-u}y_3|_0^u + e^{-u}\frac{y_2^2}{2}|_0^u - e^{-u}y|_0^u-e^{-y_3}|_0^u \\
&=-u^2e^{-u}+\frac{1}{2}u^2e^{-u}-ue^{-u}-e^{-u}+ 1 \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}u^2e^{-u}-ue^{-u}-e^{-u}+1
\end{align}
Gamma(3,1) should look like $\frac{1}{2}u^2e^{-u}$. I think I probably made a mistake somewhere doing my integrations. Is anyone able to see where I might have made that mistake?

Comment: Do know the concept of moment generating function or characteristic function?

Answer (score 1):

There were two missing minus signs, which I've added in red below. The minus sign reappeared in the line below that.
\begin{align}
&=\int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u - y3}-e^{\color{red}{-}u +y_2 - y_2 + y_3 - y_3} + e^{-y_2-y_3} dy_2dy_3 \notag \\
&=\int_{0}^{u}\begin{bmatrix}-e^{\color{red}{-}u}\int_{0}^{u - y3}dy_2 + e^{-y3}\int_{0}^{u - y3}e^{-y_2}dy_2 \end{bmatrix} dy_3\notag \\
&=\int_{0}^{u}\begin{bmatrix}-e^{-u}y_2|_0^{u-y_3} + e^{-y_3}\times -e^{-y_2}|_0^{u-y_3}\end{bmatrix}dy_3 \notag \\
\end{align}
There was no other error in the whole of the calculation. You just missed the last step, which was to differentiate the CDF that you obtained to check that it matched the PDF of a gamma distribution (you gave the PDF of a gamma distribution, not the CDF).

$$\frac{d}{du}\left(−\frac{1}{2}u^2e^{-}-ue^{-u}-e^{-u}+1\right) = -ue^{-u} + \frac{1}{2}u^2e^{-u}-e^{-u}+ ue^{-u}+ e^{-u} = \frac{1}{2}u^2e^{-u},$$
as required.